# How to find number of occurrences based on input value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reduce

I'm attempting to find the number of occurrences based on input value for ownerId in the JavaScript Json Object below.  If the ownerId is the number "1" the result should be three since the ownerId appears 3 times.

```
ownerID: 3
```

Here is what I have so far...

```
let inputValue = 1;
let return = "";

const result = jsonResponse.jsonArray[0].info.find(
(arr) => arr.ownderID === inputValue;  );
    
var data = jsonResponse.jsonArray[0].info
        .reduce((counts, result) => {
        const inputItem = result[inputValue];
        counts[inputItem] = (counts[inputItem] || 0) + 1;
        return counts;
      }, {
      });

    return = data;
```

JSON...

```
   const jsonResponse = {
   "jsonArray": [
     {
        "info": [
            {
                "ownerId": 1,
                "carType": "Nissan",
                "houseType": "Rancher"
            },
            {
                "ownerId": 1,
                "carType": "Ford",
                "houseType": "Trailer"
            }
        ],
        "familyInfo": {
            "kids": 1,
            "tuition": "yes",
            "parentId": 7
        }
    },
    {
        "info": [
            {
                "ownerId": 3,
                "carType": "Nissan",
                "houseType": "Single"
            }
        ],
        "familyInfo": {
            "kids": 4,
            "tuition": "no",
            "parentId": 11
        }
    },
    {
        "info": [
            {
                "ownerId": 1,
                "carType": "Chevy",
                "houseType": "TownHome"
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Am I going about this the right way using find and reduce?

Comment: I think no. You only search the first info. Is this wanted behavior or do you want to search the entire JSON? Also find only gives one result, do you wanted to use filter() for more results? Also if you want to count the results, you don't need a reduce but just a .length. Could you elaborate more what input to consider with which output?

Comment: I think the names `jsonResponse` and `jsonArray` are not ideal here. JSON is largely irrelevant as you're working with a JavaScript object, not a JSON document or a JSON string. I wouldn't expect to see "jsonArray" in a JSON response from an API, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, what you need to do is count across multiple `jsonArrays` and also within the `info`s

Look at the code below, I have commented it appropriately to make it verbose.
Hope it helps.

```js
const jsonResponse = {
  "jsonArray": [{
      "info": [{
          "ownerId": 1,
          "carType": "Nissan",
          "houseType": "Rancher"
        },
        {
          "ownerId": 1,
          "carType": "Ford",
          "houseType": "Trailer"
        }
      ],
      "familyInfo": {
        "kids": 1,
        "tuition": "yes",
        "parentId": 7
      }
    },
    {
      "info": [{
        "ownerId": 3,
        "carType": "Nissan",
        "houseType": "Single"
      }],
      "familyInfo": {
        "kids": 4,
        "tuition": "no",
        "parentId": 11
      }
    },
    {
      "info": [{
        "ownerId": 1,
        "carType": "Chevy",
        "houseType": "TownHome"
      }]
    }
  ]
}

// what to search for?
const searchOwnerId = 1;

// reduce to count owner id across multiple items in the list
const counts = jsonResponse.jsonArray.reduce((acc, item) => {
  // count the owner ids inside the infos
  // filter for the ownerId and length works perfect
  
  acc += item.info.filter(
    ({ownerId}) => ownerId == searchOwnerId
  ).length

  return acc

// start reduce with a zero
}, 0);

// final output
console.log(counts)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use forEach loop or reduce as given in other answer both method works fine.

```js
const jsonResponse = {
  jsonArray: [
    {
      info: [
        {
          ownerId: 1,
          carType: "Nissan",
          houseType: "Rancher",
        },
        {
          ownerId: 1,
          carType: "Ford",
          houseType: "Trailer",
        },
      ],
      familyInfo: {
        kids: 1,
        tuition: "yes",
        parentId: 7,
      },
    },
    {
      info: [
        {
          ownerId: 3,
          carType: "Nissan",
          houseType: "Single",
        },
      ],
      familyInfo: {
        kids: 4,
        tuition: "no",
        parentId: 11,
      },
    },
    {
      info: [
        {
          ownerId: 1,
          carType: "Chevy",
          houseType: "TownHome",
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
function countOccurrences(jsonResponse, inputValue) {
  let resultCount = 0;

  jsonResponse.jsonArray.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.info) {
      resultCount += item.info.filter(
        (info) => info.ownerId === inputValue
      ).length;
    }
  });

  return resultCount;
}

const inputValue = 1;
const result = countOccurrences(jsonResponse, inputValue);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're acquainted with the [@ut8pia/classifier](https://github.com/ut8pia/classifier) library you'll recognize that navigating a tree is simplified by employing a `queue` and defining a search `space` function responsible for retrieving all the children of each node.

```
const 
    space = node => node.children,
    search = new ArrayQueue()
        .let(root)
            .search(space)
```

The method `search(space)` navigates through all the descendants of the `root` node. To be returned is the formal definition of an iteration providing further methods to restrict, compose, transform and resolve the iteration.

Let's apply this paradigm, which is called the "search and selection" pattern, to define a function `n(key, value, root)` that counts the occurrences of nested objects with the specified `value` for the property `key`.

```
function n(key, value, root) {
    const
        space = obj => typeof(obj) === 'string'? []
            : Object.values(obj),

        search = new ArrayQueue()
            .let(root)
                .search(space)
                    .which(obj => obj[key]===value),

        got = search
            .what((n, _) => n+1, 0);

    return got
}
```

When using the method `Object.values()` on a parent object, all the child objects can be accessed as values associated with the parent properties. This method functions properly even when the parent is an array or a primitive (returning `[]` in this case). However, if the parent is a string, the child objects must be explicitly set as `[]` to prevent retrieving individual characters as components.

The method `which(predicate)` restricts the `search` to the objects satisfying the `predicate`, whereas the method `what(op, start)` resolves the `search`. These methods are analogous to the methods `filter(predicate)` and `reduce(op, start)` found in the Array class but they are designed to handle even infinite-length iterations.

It's important to highlight that the suggested solution doesn't assume any specific depth for the `ownerId` property within the `data` object.

In `Node.js` you can check the validity of the proposed solution by:

```
import { ArrayQueue } from "@ut8pia/classifier/queue/ArrayQueue.js";
import assert from "assert";

    const data = {
        "jsonArray": [
          {
             "info": [
                 {
                     "ownerId": 1,
                     "carType": "Nissan",
                     "houseType": "Rancher"
                 },
                 {
                     "ownerId": 1,
                     "carType": "Ford",
                     "houseType": "Trailer"
                 }
             ],
             "familyInfo": {
                 "kids": 1,
                 "tuition": "yes",
                 "parentId": 7
             }
         },
         {
             "info": [
                 {
                     "ownerId": 3,
                     "carType": "Nissan",
                     "houseType": "Single"
                 }
             ],
             "familyInfo": {
                 "kids": 4,
                 "tuition": "no",
                 "parentId": 11
             }
         },
         {
             "info": [
                 {
                     "ownerId": 1,
                     "carType": "Chevy",
                     "houseType": "TownHome"
                 }
             ]
         }
       ]
     },

     got = n('ownerId', 1, data),

     expected = 3;

assert.equal(got, expected)
```

Importing `ArrayQueue` into an `HTML` page requires execution of the script file `classifier.bundle.js` which is publicly avaible from the `jsdelivr` network. This script creates a global object `classifier` in the browser execution environment, hierarchically offering all the library's content, as follows.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ut8pia/classifier@0.0.1-19/trg/classifier.bundle.js"></script>
<script>
  var
    ArrayQueue = classifier.queue.ArrayQueue
</script>
```